# Use of нужно with the dative

Tags: грамматика

What affects how the ending of нужно should be changed?  A corrected sentence I wrote reads

> Ксения говорила, Мне нужно его общество как собаке нужны блохи.

Why are нужно and нужны used? (And I realize now that Russians say как собаке пятая нога which is not exactly something said in English, but it's clever!)

Does надо also change similarly depending on what noun is associated with it?

Comment: This is incorrect sentence.

Comment: Just to add, `нужно/нужны` are in essence shortened adjectives `нужное/нужные` that's why they should correspond to the object. But in combination with verbs it only has a neuter form `Мне нужно (было/будет) уйти`

Comment: Some little fix. [Direct speech](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C) in this case must be: `Ксения говорила: "Мне нужно его общество как собаке нужны блохи".`

Comment: An analogue in (awkward but grammatically correct) English: "to me a car is needed" and "to me two cars are needed." Would you ask why the first sentence needs is and the second needs are? This is essentially the same as what is happening in your sentence with нужно and нужны.

Answer (score 6):

Ending of `нужно` depends on the grammatical gender and plurality of associated noun.
Your example should be:

> Мне нужн**о** его общество как собаке нужны блохи.

Nouns:

1. `общество`: neuter gender, singular. Correct form: `нужно`.
2. `блохи`: plural. Correct form: `нужны`.

Alternative word `надо` has the only form, but it cannot completely replace word `нужно`.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern with нужно (an adjective, short form) is 
Кому/чему(Dative) нужно (нужен, нужна, нужны) кто, что ( Nominative ).

> Ему нужно одеяло. Мне нужна рубашка. Им нужны деньги.(The ending corresponds to the gender of the noun  ).

You can sometimes find genitive case after нужно as a predicative ( in fiction, archaic )

> Мне нужно денег.

Надо (predicative ) in the same function has got the pattern but it cannot always replace нужно.

Кому /чему надо (doesn't change ) кого/что (Accusative ) or чего(Genitive )

> Мне надо воды. Мне нужна вода.Для этого дела надо особого работника.Для этого дела нужен особый работник. Вам что надо?Вам что нужно?

We do not consider other meanings of these words.

Comment: `надо` i believe is a reduced form of `надобно` which is as well an adjective like `нужнo` and therefore declinable unless refers to a verb

Comment: НАДОБНО — НАДОБНО, в знач. сказ., с неопред., кого (что) или чего (устар. и прост.). Нужно, требуется. Н. успеть. Н. помощника. Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949 1

Comment: Надобно is a short form of надобный.

Comment: is it? i'd guess they're on the same footing only differing in gender `надобно/е - надобен/ный - надобна/я` they're all replaceable with `надо`

Comment: на́до

диал. на́доть – то же, с част. -ть из ти, впервые др.-русск. надо "до́лжно", Полоцк. грам. 1264 г. (см. Срезн. II, 277). Из др.-русск. надобѣ (еще в Полоцк. грам. 1407 г.; см. Напьерский 131). Дат., местн. ед. ч. от др.-русск. надоба "надобность, потребность", совр. на́доба – то же, на́добный; см. Бернекер 1, 203; Соболевский, Лекции 149; Мi. ЕW 47; Преобр. I, 187. См. до́ба.

Comment: Из «Русской грамматики»:
§ 1653… Предикативы – это слова с модальными значениями долженствования, необходимости, возможности. Это – самостоятельные слова, не соотносительные с качественными наречиями и краткими прилагательными; например, должно, можно, надо, нельзя, нужно...

Comment: modal words could have originally developed from adjectives